# ES6 class with getter and setter methods

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am looking at one of the examples of ES6 class using getter/setter;

```
class CoffeeMachine {
  _waterAmount = 0;

  set waterAmount(value) {
    if (value < 0) throw new Error("Negative water");
    this._waterAmount = value;
  }

  get waterAmount() {
    return this._waterAmount;
  }

  constructor(power) {
    this._power = power;
  }

}

// create the coffee machine
let coffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine(100);

// add water
coffeeMachine.waterAmount = -10; // Error: Negative water
```

I wanted to understand how the following line works;

```
coffeeMachine.waterAmount = -10
```

My question is specifically, we have used "_waterAmount" and not "waterAmount" anywhere inside the class

So 3 places inside the class;

```
_waterAmount = 0; // At class level
this._waterAmount = value; // Inside set
return this._waterAmount; // Inside get
```

With that the case, how is it mapping "waterAmount" to "_waterAmount" ?

Comment: You have already defined the mapping by putting `_waterAmount` inside get & set. Even if you rename `_waterAmount` to `_amount` in all places, code will still work.

Comment: ok...and is the actual property on the class "waterAmount" OR "_waterAmount" ?

Comment: @testndtv There's two properties, `._waterAmount` which is the data property and (inherited from prototype) `.waterAmount` which is the accessor property. (And another data property `._power` defined in your constructor)

Comment: Thanks....Just one more thing..
For _waterAmount = 0; , is it the same as if we define inside constructor() {this._waterAmount = 0;}

Comment: ....Meaning if we remove as data property outside and just add it inside constructor (like _power ), is that the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

`_waterAmount = 0` uses the [candidate](https://tc39.es/process-document/) [public instance field syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) (see [also](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)) for classes  to define an own property `_waterAmount` on each object instance created by the class.

`set waterAmount(value) { ... }` uses the [set syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) (introduced in ES5) to define a setter property on the `.prototype` of the class. The resulting property will exist on the `[[Prototype]]` (`__proto__`) of instances created by the class.

`get waterAmount(value) { ... }` uses the [get syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) to define a getter property on the `.prototype` of the class. Again, this will exist on the `[[Prototype]]` of instances created by the class.

The target of a function (ie. the "this" value) is usually determined by how it is invoked. When you write `coffeeMachine.waterAmount = -10`, the `waterAmount` property is found on the `[[Prototype]]` of `coffeeMachine`. The class associates a setter function with this property, which is invoked as part of the normal behavior of setters.

So `coffeeMachine.waterAmount = -10` invokes the setter function associated with the `waterAmount` property on the `[[Prototype]]` of `coffeeMachine` **as a method on `coffeeMachine`**. The `this` in `this._waterAmount = value` is therefore `coffeeMachine`, and the own property `_waterAmount` on `coffeeMachine` then has the value `20` assigned to it.

You can see how the class configures the various properties by using [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors):

```js
class CoffeeMachine {
  _waterAmount = 0

  set waterAmount(value) {
    if (value < 0) throw new Error("Negative water")
    this._waterAmount = value
  }

  get waterAmount() {
    return this._waterAmount
  }

  constructor(power) {
    this._power = power
  }
}

const myCoffeeMachine = new CoffeeMachine()
const x = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(myCoffeeMachine)
const y = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(myCoffeeMachine.__proto__)
console.log('myCoffeeMachine: ', x)
console.log('myCoffeeMachine.__proto__: ', y)
```